Can't connect to DB server after succesfull connection creation on MySQL Workbench
I'm a newbie in AWS and DBs in general, I've been following an old Udemy course on Amazon Web Services (AWS) - Zero to Hero, where the instructor creates a RDS DB on AWS and uses MySQL Workbench to access the DB. When I exactly follow what he does I get the following error

I could succesfully create a connection using the endpoint from DB instance.


It's not asking a password at any stage.
But when clicking on connection, it throws the error above

How can I resolve this issue?
EDIT


Have you saved the db password by clicking "Store in Vault"? If not do that and try again

@Aravindanvaithialingam, I haven't done since the instructor didn't show, however, even after storing the password in the vault, it is throwing the same error.

Does it take a few seconds to fail (eg 10 seconds), or does it fail immediately? If it takes some time, this suggests that there is no network connectivity. What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the Amazon RDS database? Also, was the database launched in a public subnet?

it takes some time (~5s) to fail. I am not sure what configuration you are referring to but I added the screenshot of Security and Networking. Have a look.

why does it say unable to connect to localhost? You shouldn't be using localhost to connect to RDS from your local machine.
Other sources of errors might be that the security group does not allow 3306 from your IP or that there is a NACL around the subnet which blocks access

@Korgen, I followed what the instructor showed, so no idea why it's trying to connect to localhost. Do you know any way to make it happen?

Today I succesfully made a connection. This time while creating a DB on RDS, I selected to Create new at VPC security group:



In my previous failed attempts it was Choose existing by default (the instructor recommended to leave it as is), therefore I must have missed that part.
Thank you everyone in the comments section to make me ponder about this.
